# Reduce repeated method call when testing condition and updating value (java)

Tags: java, performance

Suppose a condition check contains a method call to get a value. If condition is fulfilled, you use the value returned by the method for a value update. Here a simplified example.

```
// x and maxValue are e.g. both int, methodCall(x) returns int    
if (methodCall(x) > maxValue) maxValue = methodCall(x);
```

Does the JVM call methodCall 2 times if condition fulfilled? Is there a way to avoid this performance loss (without assigning methodCall(x) to a local variable sacrificing memory and computational time) and re-use the result from the condition check directly for the assignment?

Hargen

Comment: Something like `(proper type) temp; if ((temp = methodCall(x)) > maxValue) maxValue = temp;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the method is called two times. If you want to call it only one times, you need to save the result in a variable before the `if`.

```
int value = methodCall(x);
if (value > maxValue) maxValue = value;
```

Please note that the value is saved in a local variable (and not a field).

**Edit**: A more elegant solution for this usecase (as pointed out by bcsb1001 in comments) is to use [`Math#max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-):

```
maxValue = Math.max(methodCall(x), maxValue);
```

Comment: In doing this, you secrifice extra memory and extra computational power for the assignment. Especially if the condition is fulfilled rarely, this is not useful.

Comment: @HargenHans Seriously? This makes no difference to 'memory and computational power'. Although, if it satisfies your needs, you can always use [`Math.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-).

Comment: When using a local variable, it gets added to the stack. It gets cleaned up as soon as the method (or scope) is left. Calling another method (which probably does some calculation) is expensive.

Comment: if it´s an int, I agree. If it´s a very big object instead, it would make a difference. Math.max() is useful if looking for the maximum but not if we are talking about any kind of condition in the if clause

Comment: @Hargen.Hans - A read from a method local variable is always cheaper than a method call (assuming no JIT optimizations occur).  I see no reason for making a new method call instead of always storing the value in a local variable. This is a case of premature optimization.

Comment: Thanks :) That explains it.